# How to send a new document to my mongodb database but a write error is coming?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have created a new database called admins and a collection in it called programmers in my cluster in mongodb....also there is already one document in it.... I am just starting to use mongodb...this is my first code with mongodb

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

MONGODB_URI = "mongodb+srv://dada:test@cluster0-0qy57.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"#i have changed the passw
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
db = client.get_database("admins")
programmers = db.programmers

workers =programmers.estimated_document_count()
print(workers)

testData = {
    "Name": "tes",
    "Res_id": "0",
    "Role": "testcomp",
    "Age": 0
}

programmers.insert_one(testData)

workers =programmers.estimated_document_count()
print(workers)
```

Comment: Please let us to know your error. And, what version of pymongo are you using?

Comment: it says "raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.WriteError: db already exists with different case already have: [Admins] trying to create [admins]"

Comment: i am using pymongo 3.7.2